# League of Legends Login Issues

Tags: software-installation, wine, login, games, playonlinux

I installed League of Legends through PlayOnLinux. The launcher opens and I'm able to get to the login page. However it stops there. Whenever I try to login it keeps saying that I have in invalid username and password combination although I'm pretty sure I'm using the right one since I can login in a friend's computer. Did i miss a step in installing and patching LoL?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by changing my preferred server from `EU West` to `NA`.

Comment: Me too. It defaults you to EUW even if you say NA